# .htaccess подмена картинки со стороннего ресурса

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть картинка `http://kartinka.com.ua/images/2_mainpage.png`

Возможно ли с помощью *.htaccess* или *php* сделать так, чтобы ее можно было видеть по адресу `http://мойсайт.ком/img/2_mainpage.png`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Вот простейший пример:

Содержимое `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/2_mainpage.png$ /test.php [L]
```

Содержимое `test.php`:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo file_get_contents('http://kartinka.com.ua/images/2_mainpage.png');
```

Comment: а если 15000 новостей и в каждой картинка?)

Comment: @Denis, думаю, тогда тот сайта заблокирует ip вашего сервера для доступа :)

Comment: @Denis Подход не изменится, если не хотите картинки хранить у себя.
Или вы спрашиваете о масках для перенаправлений? Так реализацию масок я специально оставил для вас, поскольку из одного примера маску не собрать.

Comment: та не) там почти все разные сайты с картинками)